# How to remove sort direction gray background on JFace table

Tags: jface

I am performing sort on JFace table columns, and using the sort directions SWT.UP and SWT.DOWN to indicate the directions of sort, but gray background is getting displayed on the empty part of the column where there is no data, how do I remove that?. If that is not possible how can we place images of up arrow or down arrow on table header?

Comment: `setSortDirection` normally shows a direction image in the column header, but this may vary depending on the platform.

Comment: Yes, but when use that I am getting gray background for that particular column and I need to remove that gray background, is it possible?

Comment: Not that I know of. Again this depends on the native control and is therefore platform specific behavior, on my Mac you don't get this.

Comment: Ok greg thank you, I am using windows, so I have to figure a way to remove that